# Retrieve data from wp_postmeta

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I know this is maybe a dumb question. I am trying to retrieve data from the wordpress table wp_postmeta, specifically the meta_value column. Is there a function in php to get every field from that kind of data?

For example how can I get the  "Gabriela Castro en Costa Rica" value from this

```
a:1:{s:14:"billing-seller";a:3:{s:4:"name";s:14:"billing-seller";s:5:"value";s:29:"Gabriela Castro en Costa Rica";s:5:"label";s:26:"Select one option, please.";}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you querying the data from? A plugin/your theme's template functions.php file, or an "external" script?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a serialized array, im not familiar with Wordpress but maybe try something like this:

```
get_user_meta( '99999', 'your-key', true );
```

You can find more information to get_user_meta here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9716/how-to-retrieve-the-value-stored-in-a-multi-dimensional-array-and-sum-the-entrie

Comment: thanks, I tried but reading the documentation I see I need a user id, and my code doesn't have one

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_meta()` is the function you need to use.

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', true );
```

Where `$value` will be your string.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the serialized string I posted came from doing this:

```
get_post_meta($order->orders, '_custom_billing_fields', true);
```

That was giving me this(the original question):

```
a:1:{s:14:"billing-seller";a:3:{s:4:"name";s:14:"billing-seller";s:5:"value";s:29:"Gabriela Castro en Costa Rica";s:5:"label";s:26:"Select one option, please.";}}
```

Now this is what I did to get the value I was trying to substract:

```
$sellerBigArray = (array)maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($order->orders, '_custom_billing_fields', true));

$sellerArray=$sellerBigArray['billing-seller'];

$seller=$sellerArray['value'];
```

I hope it helps.

Bye